# But is is spam? (question that might just be an attempt to drag eyeballs.)

Tags: discussion, spam

From time to time I see a question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724253/convert-pdf-to-flash-how-to-download) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu3km.png)). Because I am hopelessly cynical, I'm tempted to wonder if the OP is just artlessly flogging the linked site. However, they *could* just be trying to get something for nothing. Anyone else got some thoughts on how to decide?

Comment: If only @QPaysTaxes would have 10k to fix the screenshot :D

Comment: @Braiam That's dealt with, [thanks to Nathan Oliver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/49900).

Answer (score 5):

Spam for sure, given the earlier answers in [the user's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/449168/user449168).

Comment: Agreed, this is spam.  I don't mind answers that promote your own site when it directly answers the original question, but I hate this kind of astroturfing.